# Quickly check Wifi speed on Windows 11

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, windows-11

I know I can search for and open the old "Network and Sharing Center" (Or run `ncpa.cpl`), click on the connection, and this dialog will show my speed:

[image]

Is there a faster way, or a shortcut that opens it directly? I would love to check this info on the tooltip of a tray icon. My adapter is a Intel AX210 with latest drivers.

Comment: Use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and drag-drop the bullseye icon on top of this dialog. This will find the owner process. Double-click on the process to find out its call command.

Comment: @harrymc thanks, found the command `C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe /factory,{5BD95610-9434-43C2-886C-57852CC8A120} -Embedding` but calling that produces nothing. Tried without `-Embedding` but also no go.

Comment: There are third-party tools that might provide the info, such as WifiInfoView, https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wifi_information_view.html . You can leave it running, or pin to taskbar or make a desktop shortcut

Comment: Thanks @DrMoishePippik but that tool dont show what I need.

Comment: To note, that "speed" reported is the WiFi link speed which says nothing about the real speed you're getting to any resources (local or over the internet)

Answer (score 2):

You could make a shortcut to a command file which just contains:

```
@echo off
netsh wlan show interfaces |find "Receive"
pause Done
```

This will show:

```
Receive rate (Mbps)    : 300
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try checking out [**NetSetMan**](https://www.netsetman.com/en/freeware) which can display this information on its system-tray pop out:
[image]